# Different color for Different Faces of Convex Hull

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

```
P0={0,0,0};P1={1,0,0};P2={0,1,0};P3={0,0,1};P4={1,1,1};P5={-1,-1,-1};
R[4]=ConvexHullMesh[{P0,P1,P3,P4},Frame->True,PlotRange -> Automatic,MeshCellStyle -> {{2,All}-> Opacity[.4, Red],{1,All}->Black,{0,All}->Blue}];

Show[Region[R[4], PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2},{-1.2,1.2}}, 
  Axes-> True, ImageSize -> Large,AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},LabelStyle ->{12,Bold,Black},AxesLabel->{x,y,z},AxesStyle->Thick,Boxed->True]]
```

I have the following 3D convex hull. How can I give different colors to different faces of the convex hull?

Thank you

Comment: "different sides" - you mean "different faces", yes?

Comment: Yes. Different faces. I will edit it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
faces = MeshPrimitives[R[4], "Polygons"];
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange};

Graphics3D[Transpose@{colors , faces}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, Axes -> True, 
 ImageSize -> Large, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to change the opacity of the colors so that the we don't see the axis lines through the hull?

Comment: @Sumit, you can define `colors` as `colors = Opacity[.5, #]& /@ {Red, Green, Blue, Orange}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Sumit, my pleasure.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add text or epilog in this 3D plot?

Comment: you can try something like `Epilog -> {Inset[Style["text", 16, Red], {.5, .7}], 
  Text[Style["text2", 16, Green], {.3, .4}]}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107179/discussion-between-sumit-banik-and-kglr).